# Play a sound as background (no controls visible) using Angular Js

Tags: angularjs, cordova, visual-studio-2015

There's a way to play a background sound (no controls visible) using Angular Js? I'm developing an app (Cordova visual studio tools).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Leogreen,
Welcome to Cordova/Phonegap. Anything that needs to be done on Cordova/Phonegap is done with a plugin. You can use a ["core" plugin](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.4.0/cordova/plugins/pluginapis.html) or a [third party plugin](http://cordova.apache.org/plugins/).

For your task, you want to use one of the "core" plugin the:

- [media plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-media)

**NOTE:** This is not the old HTML `<audio>` element, and it is NOT the [HTML5 `<audio>`](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_audio.asp) element. Those also play audio in the background. --Best of Luck